# How do i fix this code in random walk problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

[image]

```
#include<iostream>   
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
     int arr[5][5] = { 0 };
int x =0, y = 0;
int mx,my;
int cnt = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
while(1) {
    bool a = true;
    int i = rand() % 8;
    if (i == 0) {
        mx = -1, my = 0;
        if ((x + mx) > 4 || (x + mx) < 0 || (y + my) > 4 || (y + my) < 0) continue;
        arr[x + mx][y + my] ++;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        cnt++;
        }
    if (i == 1) {
        mx = 1, my = -1;
        if ((x + mx) > 4 || (x + mx) < 0 || (y + my) > 4 || (y + my) < 0) continue;
        arr[x + mx][y + my]++;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        cnt++;
     }
     if (i == 2) {
        mx = 0, my = -1;



        if ((x + mx) > 4 || (x + mx) < 0 || (y + my) > 4 || (y + my) < 0) continue;
        arr[x + mx][y + my] ++;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        cnt++;
        }
    if (i == 3) {
        mx = 1, my = 1;
        if ((x + mx) > 4 || (x + mx) < 0 || (y + my) > 4 || (y + my) < 0) continue;
        arr[x + mx][y + my] ++;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        cnt++;
        }
    if (i == 4) {
        mx = 1, my = 0;
        if ((x + mx) > 4 || (x + mx) < 0 || (y + my) > 4 || (y + my) < 0) continue;
        arr[x + mx][y + my] ++;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        cnt++;
        }
    if (i == 5) {
        mx = 1, my = -1;
        if ((x + mx) > 4 || (x + mx) < 0 || (y + my) > 4 || (y + my) < 0) continue;
        arr[x + mx][y + my] ++;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        cnt++;
        }
    if (i == 6) {
        mx = 0, my = -1;
        if ((x + mx) > 4 || (x + mx) < 0 || (y + my) > 4 || (y + my) < 0) continue;
        arr[x + mx][y + my] ++;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        cnt++;
    }
    if (i == 7) {
        mx = -1, my = -1;
        if ((x + mx) > 4 || (x + mx) < 0 || (y + my) > 4 || (y + my) < 0) continue;
        arr[x + mx][y + my]++;
        x += mx;
        y += my;
        cnt++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 0) a = false;
        }
    }
    if (a == true)break;
}
cout << cnt;
return 0;
}
```

I'm solving a random walk algorithm problem, but I don't know where it is wrong.
When I compile, nothing is displayed on the black screen. 
It was lengthened by not using functions, but I think there is nothing wrong with it.
If there are any parts that can cause errors, please explain
thanks for reading this post i'm waiting your answer

Comment: Did you run the program after compiling it?

Comment: btw "When I compile, nothing is displayed on the black screen", just compiled or did you run the program?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that your various `if` do not explore all the possible movements you can do given you are in a position x, y. For example, if you see what you do at `i == 2`

```
if (i == 2) {
    mx = 0, my = -1;
```

or, at `i == 6`

```
if (i == 6) {
    mx = 0, my = -1;
```

you do the same thing. In particular: look at this:

```
- - V
V X V
V V V
```

You miss the two movements going up and up-left.

I would review the various if movements (that you save in those two variables, mx and my)

As an improvement to your code, I'd choose a random move only between the ones you can really do.. it would be more clean.